# KnockoutJS binding fails in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js

The following knockout binding works fine in real browsers, but fails in IE8 (and IE9 in compatibility mode)

```
<li data-bind="attr: { class: id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? 'active' : '' }">
```

[image]

Does anyone know why, and how I can fix it?

---

Here's the whole code, if that helps:

```
<div class="toc-outer">
    <ol id="table-of-contents" data-bind="sortable: { data: list, template: 'listTemplate', allowDrop: false, isEnabled: false }" class="toc toc-tree"></ol>
</div>

<script id="listTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="attr: { class: id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? 'active' : '' }">
        <div data-bind="attr: { class: 'dropdown' + (id() == $root.currentItem().parentId() ? ' active' : '') }">
            <a href="#" class="toggle">
                <i data-bind="visible:children().length > 0, attr: { class: 'icon-toggle icon-minus hide' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="dropdown-toggle menu"
                href="#"
                data-bind="visible:$root.allowEditing"
                data-toggle="dropdown">

                <i data-bind="attr: { class: 'icon-menu icon-list-alt hide' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="name" data-bind="attr: {href: hash}">
                <i data-bind="visible: type() == 'settings', attr: { class: 'icon-type icon-settings icon-home' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
                <i data-bind="visible: type() == 'video', attr: { class: 'icon-type icon-video icon-facetime-video' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
                <i data-bind="visible: type() == 'data', attr: { class: 'icon-type icon-data icon-signal' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
                <i data-bind="visible: type() == 'file', attr: { class: 'icon-type icon-file icon-download-alt' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
                <i data-bind="visible: type() == 'test', attr: { class: 'icon-type icon-test icon-ok-sign' + (id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? ' icon-white' : '') }"></i>
                <span data-bind="text:name"></span>
                <span class="badge draft" data-bind="visible:status() == 'draft'">D</span>
            </a>
            <dl class="dropdown-menu" data-bind="visible:$root.allowEditing">
                <dd><a href="#" data-bind="visible: parentId() !== 0 && !topLevelChild(), click: moveOut" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocMoveOut}" class="moveItemOut">#{TocMoveOut}</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#" data-bind="visible: parentId() !== 0 && !firstSibling(), click: moveIn" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocMoveIn}" class="moveItemIn">#{TocMoveIn}</a></dd>
                <dd data-bind="visible: parentId() !== 0 && (!topLevelChild() || !firstSibling())" class="divider"></dd>
                <dd><a href="#" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocEdit}" class="edit">#{TocEdit}</a></dd>
                <dd data-bind="visible: parentId() !== 0"><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></dd>
                <dd class="divider"></dd>
                <dd><a href="#page" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocAddPage}" class="add">#{TocAddPage}</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#video" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocAddVideo}" class="add">#{TocAddVideo}</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#file" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocAddFile}" class="add">#{TocAddFile}</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#test" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocAddTest}" class="add">#{TocAddTest}</a></dd>
                <dd><a href="#data" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocAddData}" class="add">#{TocAddData}</a></dd>
                <dd class="divider"></dd>                                
                <dd><a href="#library" data-toggle="pill" data-target="#item-pane" title="#{TocAddLibrary}" class="add add-from-library">#{TocAddLibrary}</a></dd>
            </dl>                            
        </div>
        <span class="divider" data-bind="visible: type() == 'settings'"></span>
        <ol class="toc-child" data-bind="sortable: {template: 'listTemplate', data:children, isEnabled: $root.allowEditing(), beforeMove: beforeTreeItemMove, afterMove: tocSorted, allowDrop: false }"></ol>
    </li>
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you stayed away from knockout's **"css" binding**?

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html

It's good to know you found the problem in IE, and you found a work-around, 
but as it's not in the documentation for "attr" binding, 
and the "css" binding *seems* to be knockout's recommended course 
of action for applying class names, might it not be confusing 
for you or others down the road?

From the [knockout documentation for "css" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

> "**Purpose**
>
> The `css` binding adds or removes one or more named **CSS classes** [*emphasis added*] to the associated DOM element. This is useful, for example, to highlight some value in red if it becomes negative.
>
> (Note: If you don’t want to apply a CSS class but instead want to assign a style attribute value directly, see the style binding.)"

Comment: Here are the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/attr-binding.html) for the attr binding.  The CSS binding is for setting CSS properties like margin or padding.  I was trying to set the class *attribute*

Comment: @AdamRackis - I don't see in the documentation that the css binding is for setting individual style properties. Rather, the documentation for css binding, part of which I've added to the answer, shows it is for css classes. Also, the css documentation says to "assign a style attribute" if you want to directly add a specific css property.

Answer (score 20):

It seems IE8 is confused by the word `class`, so it needs to be in quotes.  So

```
<li data-bind="attr: { class: id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? 'active' : '' }">
```

becomes

```
<li data-bind="attr: { 'class': id() == $root.currentItem().id() ? 'active' : '' }">
```

Comment: +1 this was very helpful. Also I found that word `switch` is causing same errors, even if used it in a template as `click: $parent.switch` which was very weird.

Comment: for: is another attribute that caught me, needs to be 'for': to work in IE < 9.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer for this question. simple and straight forward. And yes, we all hate IE8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18240063/ie8-throws-this-command-is-not-supported-error-when-using-knockout-for-data-bi also helped me.