# IE8 throws "This command is not supported" error when using knockout for data binding using attr type

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Code:-

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.3.0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>InputType</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: settings">
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td><input data-bind="attr: {type: dtype}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = function(){
        this.settings = ko.observableArray([{name: "Bungle",dtype:"text"},{name: "George",dtype: "checkbox"},{name: "Zippy",dtype:"text"}]);
    };

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is also captured in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uByVQ/ . While, the scenario captured in the fiddle runs fine in chrome it does not run properly in IE8. I get the error

"This command is not supported".

I am using knockout 2.3

Can anyone point me to a work around?

Thanks.

Comment: Im getting a lot of Google results indicating you cannot change the type of an element in IE once its been added to the DOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that in IE, you can't change the type of an input element once it's been added to the DOM.

> The type property is read/write-once, but only when an input element is created with the createElement method and before it is added to the document.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534700.aspx

There are some ugly work-arounds that involve creating a new element and deleting the existing one, but you would have to write a custom knockout binder to accomplish that.

You might could get around it with the `if` [binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html):

```
<tr>
    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
    <td>
        <span data-bind="if: dtype=='checkbox'"><input  type='checkbox' /></span>
        <span data-bind="if: dtype=='text'"><input  type='text' /></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/GQEs5/

But this is really unsatisfying and verbose.

I would also add that its philosophically impure to have presentation details in your Model, but I definitely recognize the pragmatic benefits of your approach.